# Display a Popover when mouseover an event in fullcalendar Angular 6

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, mouseover, popover

I am using Fullcalendar in an Angular 6 project, and I want to display a popover when the mouse hover an event

With this code I dont have a problem in my consol but also nothing is displaying

TS File :

```
    PopOver(elem): void {
    console.log(elem);
    $(elem.element).popover({
      title: 'the title',
      content: 'qsdqsd',
      placement: 'top',
      trigger: 'manual',
      delay: { show: 200, hide: 100 },
      animation: true,
      container: '#calendar',
      html: true,
    }).popover('show');
  }
```

HTML File :

```
 <div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
        <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar
                         [options]="calendarOptions"
                         (eventResize)="draging($event)"
                         (eventStartEditable)="true"
                         (eventDrop)="draging($event)"
                         (eventMouseover)="PopOver(this)"
                         (eventMouseout)="undisplay()"
        ></ng-fullcalendar>
      </div>
```

I tried many other solution but nothing Please I need an answer it's important for me

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is late, but I found a workaround for this.

My Html

```html
<div *ngIf="calendarOptions">
          <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)" (eventDrop)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
              (eventResize)="updateEvent($event.detail)" (clickButton)="clickButton($event.detail)"></ng-fullcalendar>
      </div>
```

My Typescript for eventClick method

eventClick(model: any) {

```
var popTemplate = [
    '<div class="popover" style="max-width:600px;" >',
    '<div class="arrow"></div>',
    '<div class="popover-header">',
    '<button id="closepopover" type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>',
    '<h3 class="popover-title"></h3>',
    '</div>',
    '<div class="popover-content"></div>',
    '</div>'].join('');
    $('.popover').not(model.jsEvent.currentTarget).popover('hide');
    $(model.jsEvent.currentTarget).popover({
        title: 'the title',
        content: function () {
            return "This <em>rich</em>  <pre>html</pre> content goes inside popover";
        },
        template: popTemplate,
        placement: 'left',
        html: true,
        trigger: 'click',
        animation: true,
        container: 'body'
    }).popover('show');
```

}

I hope this helps someone